# git change origin of a branch (rebase)

Tags: git, branch, rebase

f'I have the following:

```
A---B---C-----D--   branch dev
     \--C'-E-/      branch test
```

I did it bad: C and C' are almost the same commits, it would make more sense if I could make branch *test* start on C, instead of B.

How could I do that?, I guess rebase, but I'm not sure how to use it, thx

**edit**: wasn't clear
what I'd like:

```
A---B---C-----D--   branch dev
         \-E-/      branch test
```

or

A--B--D--E--D if not possible

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could rebase it on top of a temporary branch (made from `C`)
See [`git rebase`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase) and [Rebasing](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Branching-Rebasing), plus [`git branch`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-branch).

```
git branch tmp C
git checkout test

# rebase the current branch (test) on top of tmp
git rebase tmp  

git branch -d tmp
```

That should give you:

```
A---B---C-----D--       branch dev
         \--C''-E'-/      branch test
```

I have left C' (here as C'') because C' isn't *exactly* the same than C.
But as [ams](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1057909/ams) comments, if you need C' gone, you would

```
git rebase -i tmp
```

That would get you an *interactive* rebase, allowing for `C'` to be removed completely, replaying only `E` on top of `C`.

Comment: but I need to remove C' then, keep just E in the other branch, that's just the important commit

Comment: I'm not sure why @VonC has left `C''` in there. As I understand it, `C'` should have been removed entirely. If it doesn't, then you can use `git rebase -i tmp` and delete the line with `C'` on it.

Comment: Also, doing this rebase would make branch `test` look better, but the old version will live on in the history of `D`, not that you might care about that. If `dev` is a local branch nobody else has seen yet, you could also `git reset` that to `C` and redo the merge.

Comment: @ciril I have edited the answer to allow for `C'` to be removed.

Answer (score 8):

You can rebase just the piece you want onto C:

```
A---B---C-----D--   branch dev
     \
      C'-E--      branch test

# git rebase --onto [new base] [starting after this commit] [ending at this commit]
git rebase --onto C C' E

A---B---C-----D--   branch dev
         \
          E--      branch test
```

It's the same concept as cherry-picking, except the `test` branch pointer moves along with the rebased commits.

(Note that the C' commit will be unreachable after the rebase, but you can get back to it with `git reflog`.)

Comment: I need to be on branch test to do that? I already merged test from dev

Comment: For the `--onto` flag, it doesn't matter which branch you're on, because you're telling it exactly what to do: "Starting there, move everything up to that onto this". I'm not sure what you mean by "merged test from dev".

Comment: E joins D, D is a merge between the 2 branches

Comment: Ah, I missed that. You may want to update your question. It sounds like what you want is `A---B---C---E`, is that right?

Comment: Your explanation made me understand rebase for the first time! Thank you